# Cannot see certain network directory on MacOS

Tags: macos, network, sharing

We have a Windows domain with a few Macs connected. They can see the network shares no problem but there are some directories where the name begins with a full stop. The Macs cannot see these for some reason.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: File/Directory names beginning with `.` are treated as hidden. To toggle the display of hidden files/directories, press the Finder keyboard shortcut, `Cmd + Shift + .`

Answer (score 1):

File/Directory names beginning with `.` are treated as hidden in macOS and are not displayed in Finder by default.

To view hidden items, invoke the Finder keyboard shortcut, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. This key combination toggles the display of hidden items in Finder, thus re-invoking it will hide the display of hidden items.

When using a Non-Apple/PC keyboard, the key equivalent to <kbd>⌘</kbd> is <kbd>Window</kbd> key. (This key is generally referred to as **Meta** key).